# After Search is Cleared, Original Data Doesn't Reappear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**UPDATE**

This works in the snippet example with the var data array, when I try to implement it into my REST example, nothing is populating the html list. I am going to move the working example to a fiddle and update the snippet with the implementation that isn't working.

Fiddle (working hard coded array): https://jsfiddle.net/v24kagL8/

I am searching through my data by WeekOf variable which is a date/time SharePoint column.

In this example the date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

Here is a test case: Everything on load is shown. Once the search bar is utilized, and the right date is entered, the values correlated with that date appear. When the search bar is cleared, no data is populated and I want that to work.

**UPDATED SNIPPET WITH FETCH**
In @freedomn-m's answer, the fix was this which works, but when I implement, nothing populates

```
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    if (value == "") {
      $("li").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('li').fadeOut(10);
      $('[data-weekof=' + value + ']').fadeIn();
    }
  });
```

Here is my updated JS which is not working:

```
function loadData(url) {
  url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport')/items?$select=DeliverablesSubmitted,MajorTasks,UpcomingTasks,UpcomingDeliverables,PersonnelActions,SupportRequest,ResourceRequest,Team/Value,Training,Upcoming,WeekOf,TravelODC";
  return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
    .then((r) => {
      if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
      return r.json();  // parse JSON
    })
    .then((data) => data.d.results);
}
loadData()
  .then((results) => {
      let data = results;
      var listContent = '';
      console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var currData = data[i];
        listContent += '<li class="test" data-weekOf="'+currData.WeekOf.split("T")[0]+'">';
        console.log(currData.WeekOf.split("T")[0]);
       if(currData.Team !== null){
        listContent += '<h2>' + currData.Team.results.join(', ') +'</h2>';
        }else{
        listContent += '<h2>' + "Null" +'</h2>';
        }
       if(currData.MajorTasks !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Major Tasks Completed </h4>';
        listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + currData.MajorTasks.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.DeliverablesSubmitted !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Deliverables Submitted</h4>';
        listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + currData.DeliverablesSubmitted.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.UpcomingTasks !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Tasks</h4>';
        listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + currData.UpcomingTasks.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.UpcomingDeliverables !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Deliverables</h4>';
        listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + currData.UpcomingDeliverables.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.PersonnelActions !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
        listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + currData.PersonnelActions.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.Upcoming !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Upcoming G3G Events </h4>';
        listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + currData.Upcoming.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       listContent += '</li>';
    }
 $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
 $('#under_txt').text(' ');
});
  $(document).ready(function(){
    loadData();
  });
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    if (value == "") {
      $("li").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('li').fadeOut(10);
      $('[data-weekof=' + value + ']').fadeIn();
    }
  });
function sortNewestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
function sortOldestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
$('a.printPage').click(function(){
        $('.container').show();
           window.print();
           return false;
});
```

Comment: Without looking too closely, you're filtering on `""` rather than clearing the filter.  `$('[data-weekOf='+value+']').fadeIn();` with empty value = `$('[data-weekOf=""]').fadeIn();` whereas it should be `$('[data-weekOf]').fadeIn();` or just `$('li).fadeIn()` (and probably remove .fadeOut()`.

Comment: Offtopic: note that `data-` should be all lowercase `data-weekof` otherwise it can get mixed up, eg `$("li").data("weekOf")` won't find it.

Comment: with empty value `'[data-weekOf='+value+']'` becomes `'[data-weekOf=]'` which is not a valid selector

Comment: @freedomn-m I madde the suggested edit and upon search the page starts blinking and doesn't filter

Comment: As @appleapple stated - it should be giving an error

Comment: Don't change the question with a possible solution - now your filter doesn't work at all

Comment: i suggest you to test the input to avoid some errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check for `value==""` then show all rather than filter to none:

```
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    if (value == "") {
      $("li").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('li').fadeOut(10);
      $('[data-weekof=' + value + ']').fadeIn();
    }
  });
```

Updated snippet

```js
var data = [
    {
      "Team": "Eagles",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": null,
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Raiders",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": null,
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": null,
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Vikings",
      "WeekOf": "2021-03-30",
      "Tasks": null,
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": null,
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    }
  ];

function onSuccess(data) {
     console.log("onsuccess")
     var listContent = [];
   
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<li data-weekof="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         if(data[i].Tasks !== null){
            listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
         }else{
              listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Deliverables !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Actions !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Billable !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';
         if(data[i].NonBillable !== null){
                 listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>';
         if(data[i].UpcomingEvents !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';
         if(data[i].Training !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Resource !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Support !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';         
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '</li>';
 }
   $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
   $('#under_txt').text(' ');
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    onSuccess(data);
  });
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    if (value == "") {
      $("li").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('li').fadeOut(10);
      $('[data-weekof=' + value + ']').fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
function sortNewestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
function sortOldestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);

}
```

```css
h2{
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 20px;
}
h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
span{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#report-summary{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#search{
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
h4{
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
#myInput{
  text-align: center;
}
#under_txt{
margin-left: 5px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
<div id="search">
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
</div>
<h1>
Weekly Manager Report
</h1>
<p>Week Of<span id="under_txt"></span></p>
<div id="report-summary">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if you want to keep the last data displayed when cleared or the data displayed at the initialization: here i display the initialization data when `value ==''`

You just relaunch Onsuccess(data) when you clear input:

```js
var data = [
    {
      "Team": "Eagles",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": null,
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Raiders",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": null,
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": null,
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Vikings",
      "WeekOf": "2021-03-30",
      "Tasks": null,
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": null,
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    }
  ];

function onSuccess(data) {
     var listContent = [];
   
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<li data-weekOf="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         if(data[i].Tasks !== null){
            listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
         }else{
              listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Deliverables !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Actions !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Billable !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';
         if(data[i].NonBillable !== null){
                 listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>';
         if(data[i].UpcomingEvents !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';
         if(data[i].Training !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Resource !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Support !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';         
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '</li>';
 }
   $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
   $('#under_txt').text(' ');
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    onSuccess(data);
  });
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if($.trim(value)==''){
        onSuccess(data);
        return;
    }
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    $('li').fadeOut(10);
    var test = $('[data-weekOf='+value+']');
    console.log(test);
    if(test.length == 0) return;
    $('[data-weekOf='+value+']').fadeIn();
  });
  
});
function sortNewestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
function sortOldestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);

}
```

```css
h2{
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 20px;
}
h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
span{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#report-summary{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#search{
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
h4{
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
#myInput{
  text-align: center;
}
#under_txt{
margin-left: 5px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
<div id="search">
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
</div>
<h1>
Weekly Manager Report
</h1>
<p>Week Of<span id="under_txt"></span></p>
<div id="report-summary">

</div>
</div>
```